# how to create Adium chat tab with AppleScript

Tags: tabs, applescript, quicksilver, adium

I use an AppleScript script to send msg to my contact through Quicksilver. It looks similarly like this ([link](http://dcortesi.com/2008/01/12/adium-quicksilver-script/)), but the line to send the message to the contact is:

```
tell account of im_contact
    set newChat to make new chat with contacts {im_contact} with new chat window
end tell
```

i.e: to send a msg to Anne, activate Quicksilver, press '.', type `anne: my message here` and it will create a new chat window with Anne with the typed message in the background (I like it in the background since I don't want the new focused window to interrupt my workflow).
The problem is for different contacts, it creates different chat windows not tabs.

I emailed the Adium for help and they asked me to try this with no success:

```
tell account of im_contact
    set newChat to make new chat with contacts {im_contact} at end of chat window 1 with new chat window
end tell
```

or

```
tell account of im_contact
    set newChat to make new chat with contacts {im_contact} at end of chat window 1 
end tell
```

How can I modify this script to make it create tabs instead of new chat windows in the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue with:

```
set existing_window to first chat window
tell account of im_contact 
    to (make new chat with contacts {im_contact} at end of (chats of existing_window))
end tell
```